# Regex function not working when one key contains the other key

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've got the following regex function:

```
for(var key in args) {
  var regex = new RegExp('{' + key + '[^}]*}', 'g');
  pattern = pattern.replace(regex, args[key]);
}
```

This makes sure when `args` looks like:

```
var args: {
  name: 'test',
  id: '12' 
}
```

And

```
pattern = "{name}/{id:[0-9]}"
```

When this function is called, `pattern` will change to `test/12`

But when `pattern` look like `{name[a-z]}/{name2[0-9]}`, `name2` gets the same value as `name` when my `args` look like:

```
var args: {
  name: 'test',
  name2: '12'
}
```

How can I edit my code to make `pattern` look like `test/12`?

Comment: Is args an array or an object?? That would explain why your for-in cycle doesn't get the correct values.. Try adding a console.log(key) in your cycle and check what is printed on console

Comment: Your pattern as posted doesn't do anything with stuff like `[a-z]` or `[0-9]`.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi sorry I edited it, it's an object with objects

Comment: @Pointy that's true, because this part could be anything and so it has to ignore that part.

Comment: @MattBurland maybe I didn't write it clear, that's my fault then, but `args` is already a JavaScript Object. I've edited my code to make I more clear I hope

Comment: @InbarAzulay: Ok - so why don't you just read it's values? Why are you doing this elaborate regex matching anyway? Also, that's not even valid javascript? What does you object actually look like? Is it an array containing objects?

Comment: I made a little mistake in my Object. I do this with regex because it needs to replace more than just the key. It had to take way the curly bracket at the start and the part after the string too. The only thing is, is that the part after the key can be anything, so I cant't look up a certain string.

Comment: What is `args[key].model`? That can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you allow any non `{`-character to follow `name`, so indeed `name2` will be matched as well.

You need to avoid that the regular expression for matching `name` does not also take `name2` as a match. One way of doing that, is to require there is a break in alphanumerical characters after matching `name`, i.e. you add `\b` in the regular expression. Since you define the regular expression as a quoted string, you'll need to escape that backslash:

```js
var args = {
  name: 'test',
  name2: '12'
};
var pattern = '{name[a-z]}/{name2[0-9]}';
for(var key in args) {
  var regex = new RegExp('{' + key + '\\b[^}]*}', 'g');
  pattern = pattern.replace(regex, args[key]);
}

console.log(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are starting with an object like this:

```
var args: {
  name: 'test',
  name2: '12'
}
```

And you want to end up with a string like this:

```
test/12
```

Then you *could* simply do something like this:

```
var myString = Object.keys(args).map(function(f) { return args[f] }).join("/");
```

However, the order that the keys are iterated in isn't guaranteed.

If instead you have an array (your question isn't clear):

```
var args: [
  { name: 'test' },
  { name2: '12' }
]
```

And assuming the objects inside you array only ever have one property. Then you could do something like:

```
args.map(function(i) { return i[Object.keys(i)[0]]; }).join("/")
```

Comment: I've already changed the object in my question. I really need to replace a part of a string. This is because the pattern can look like this: '{name}/something/{name2}' and in this case the outcome should be `test/something/12`

Comment: @InbarAzulay: Then I have no idea what you are doing. But treat objects like objects and not like strings. Doing this with regex makes zero sense and is only going to cause you endless grief. And if the order is important, then you are using the wrong structure to start with - you need an array. There is no getting around that.

Comment: Why is it wrong to use an object here? I need a list which has a key and connects it to a value. If you'd create a array for this, how would you make it look?

Comment: @InbarAzulay: As I said in my answer *the order that the keys are iterated isn't guaranteed*. If the order in the final string is important, then you need to do something else. My example above works fine in Chrome, but nothing in the Javascript spec says that keys have to be iterated in any defined order or the same order every time. So it's a very dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: The way the obect is iterated isn't of a huge value. It just had to look if his key is in the pattern. So if it first replaces the `name2` and then the `name` it's not of a huge difference for my code